# How to make use of resizable BAR?

Tags: directx11, graphics-programming, nvidia, amd

From what I understand, [resizable BAR](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/news/geforce-rtx-30-series-resizable-bar-support/) (aka. [Smart Access Memory](https://www.amd.com/en/technologies/smart-access-memory)) makes it possible to access the whole GPU memory from CPU code. But how can a programmer make use of that?

Is there an example or code snippet somewhere, that makes use of that feature? Or is that just an automatic that improves the performance of staging resources?

I'd also be happy if you can recommend further search terms that I can look up.